# Alert in forloop does not get recognie when running code (javascript)

Tags: javascript, alert

I tried to follow the tutroail on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeFzkC2awTM 
Time: 35:10

however the alert does not work,though no error is displayed when running the code.

```js
*function addItemToCart(title, price, srcImage) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
    cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0];
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title");
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innertext == title) {
            alert("Item is already added to cart");
            return;
        }
    }
    var cartItemsContent = `
             <div class="cart-item cart-column">*
                    <img class="cart-item-image" src="${srcImage}" width="100" height="100" />
                    <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
             </div>

                <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>

            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1" />
                    <button class="btn btn-danger cart-quantity-btn" type="button">
                             REMOVE
                    </button>
             </div>
    `;
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartItemsContent;
    cartItems.append(cartRow);
    cartRow
        .getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0]
        .addEventListener("click", removeCartItems);
 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a little more extensive explanation of your issue here?

Comment: The element of creating a div is working properly, however, it adds multiple divs without checking if the div added was the same or not. therefore, the alert of adding a similar div is skipping from running and it does not work. i just want to make the code checks that no similar divs with the same title should added and it should give the user an alert "Item is already added to cart"